# 'For' loop gives "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason I cannot run a simple For loop without getting this message.

This is a simple code I wrote in a sub and every time I try to run it I get the Application-defined or object-defined error message. But if I switch the (i, 2) to a set cell like (5, 2) it works:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 10

MsgBox Cells(i, 2).Value

Next i
```

Why won't it let me use cells using "i"?

Comment: Do all of your rows have a value in the second cell? There is nothing wrong with the code you provided, other than the possibility of `null` values in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

When your loop goes through its first iteration, `i` is equal to `0`.  There is no such `Cell(0,2)`.  Therefore, you get an error.

Either do `For i = 1 to 10` or change the msgbox line to `MsgBox Cells(i + 1, 2).Value`.

Without knowing what other code you have, I can't really say which one would be preferable.  But for the loop you do show, they are equivalent.

If you're going to add to that loop, or use `i` elsewhere, probably use `MsgBox Cells(i + 1, 2).Value` so you don't mess up anything else.

Comment: If that worked for you, do you mind marking as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Because Cells(0, 2).value is invalid and that's the first value you're using for i in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to access Cell(0,2) which do not exist, the code below should work

```
Dim i As Integer

   For i = 1 To 10

      MsgBox Cells(i, 2).Value

   Next i
```